# TEMP.Font Driver Host folders are created in the c:\users folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, active-directory, temporary-files

One or two months ago we are encountering a pretty weird problem.
When we log out and log in with another user a folder will be created in the c:\users folder named TEMP.Font Driver Host. If we do it again (it does not matter if we are changing from the AD user to local administrator, or to an another AD user. If we repeat this process, another folder will be created but with the name of TEMP.Font Driver Host.000 - 001, 002... So if there are four users are using the PC, and they log in with their different users, at least four folders will be created daily.
The folders are empty, we can delete it. We are also using a program called Markany Document Safer which will secure our documents, that's why you can also find korean named folders, but it was always there. So if we log in with different user, we will get a TEMP.Font Driver Host, and a korean named folder at the same time. Since we noticed these, there is no problem, but i am pretty sure it is not normal. Do you have any idea why could it be?
[image]

Comment: It’s probably the software application creating them

Comment: It could be, but we are using this software for years, and the newest update for that was pretty long time ago... :/

Comment: So the folder is being created by fontdrvhost.exe which is a legitimate file by Microsoft but it’s security was updated so it runs in an AppContainer.  So I suspect the application isn’t compatible with this change.

Comment: Today i installed a brand new PC, and I installed this document safer program only for last step. Yes, you were right, this third party software makes these folders... :( Thank you for your reply!